# char in c with multiple characters whilst not being a pointer

Tags: c, string, char

I have just came across this code in c:

```
char buf[1024];
```

What does this mean? I was under the impression `char *buf[1024]` is the only way to make a `char` a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration

```
char *buf[1024];
```

makes `buf` an array of pointers to `char`. In other words, it can be used as an array of 1024 strings.

The declaration

```
char buf[1024];
```

declares a *single* array of characters, that can contain up to 1024 characters (or a string with 1023 characters plus the terminator).

Answer (score 1):

`char buf[1024];` declares an array of type `char` with length 1024. `char *buf[1024]` would declare an array with 1024 elements of type `char *`, which could be used to point to 1024 strings. Both of these arrays would be declared on the stack.

A C string is simply a null-terminated array of `char`. So `char buf[1024];` could contain a string with 1023 characters with a null character at the end. If you wanted a pointer to a `char` array that could contain a string, `char *buf[1024]` is the wrong way to declare it. You'd need to `malloc` the space for it on the heap:

```
char* pBuf = (char*) malloc(1024);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char buf[1024];
```

is an array of chars, it means you can store several chars in only one variable. In this case, your array can store up to 1024 chars.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create strings in C, you can allocate a string statically using `char buf[1024]`, which means you are declaring a string with size 1024 at compile time; or dynamically using `char *buf`, which means you are declaring a pointer to a char (that can also be seen as a pointer to a string) that can then be allocated using `malloc` with the desired size.

As mentioned in the other answers, `char *buf[1024]` declares an array of char pointers not a string.